# Even though both are same, Im getting the error: The 'redirect_uri' parameter must be a Login redirect URI in the client app settings

Tags: node.js, okta, okta-api

in my okta application settings ,

LOGIN

Login redirect URIs :http://localhost:3000/users/callback & http://localhost:3000/

Logout redirect URIs http://localhost:3000/

and in app.js,

```
onst oidc = new ExpressOIDC({

  issuer: "https://dev-hidden.okta.com/oauth2/default",

  client_id: "hidden",

  

  client_secret: "hidden",

  appBaseUrl: "http://localhost:3000",

  redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/users/callback',

  scope: "openid profile",

  routes: {

    login: {

      path: "/users/login"

    },

    callback: {

      path: "/users/callback",

      defaultRedirect: "/dashboard"
```

as u can see redirect uri= logi redirect uri , still im getting the error

I have tried to add the base url along with the main uri which I needed  and yet no success....
any solutions?

Comment: I think you might be using wrong issuer. Please double check. Also make sure redirect url is added as a trusted origin in Okta.

Comment: I haver stuck with same issue at Python. I created Question within OKTA Community: https://support.okta.com/help/s/question/0D54z00008KB6jpCAD/flaskoidc-does-not-work-as-expected-and-is-returning-redicrecturi-error?language=en_US